# How does Codeigniter know where mysql server is located?

Tags: codeigniter

I know this is a very newbie question. So supposed we have a wamp server installed, and downloaded codeigniter. Does the codeigniter find the mysql application through the environmental variable path like it shows on the phpinfo() page? If possible, could you tell me where I can see this configuration within the codeigniter application. The database.php file doesn't seem to have mysql path.

Comment: Mysql works as daemon and it runs like service. What actually you are looking at ?.

Comment: Ok. I guess my question really is how php interacts with mysql in general. So does the php_mysql.dll tell where mysql application is? Or could you briefly explain a little bit of how otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define mysql credentials within `application/config/database.php`, so codeigniter can connect to your database.

To connect no path is required, instead you have to provide host, username and password.

In your case:

```
host: localhost
username: root
password: your default root password
```

Read here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: Like I said in my question, I can't find the mysql path in this file. How does it know where to find mysql in the first place?

Comment: No path is needed, connection works over TCP/IP, so you provide a host instead - in your case this might be localhost.

Answer (score 0):

`In general, MySQL server is to install as a Windows Service (Daemon on linux), it can be controlled from the command line, or with the graphical services utility.`

PHP interacts with MySQL by connecting to it using `TCP/IP`. So needless, we have to provide
credentials like `hostname, port(default 3306), username ,password etc` in order to connect with it. More details can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-standard.html).